# How to inject android application class with DispatchingAndroidInjector<Activity> in dagger 2

Tags: android, dagger-2

I am trying to create a constructor for android application class for injecting DispatchingAndroidInjector as I would like to inject in constructor instead of field injection.
Whenever I try to inject inside application class constructor, 'application class has no zero argument' exception is received.

Following way I am trying to inject dependency in application class :

```
    DispatchingAndroidInjector<Activity> mDispatchingAndroidInjector;

    @Inject
    public MyApplication(DispatchingAndroidInjector<Activity> dispatchingAndroidInjector) {
        mDispatchingAndroidInjector = dispatchingAndroidInjector;
    }
```

Comment: Provide the code

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are using [AppComponentFactory](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AppComponentFactory), which is available from API 28 only, your application class must have a default no-arg constructor. It basically means you can't use constructor injection for the application class.